# How to marge child data created by using group by in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, group-by, linq-to-entities

I've table with following data.

[image]

I want to group the data by DocumentID and then want to marge the DocPropIdentifyName and meta value together using comma separator. The output will be like following:

[image]

I'm doing it by using a foreach like below:

```
var test = (from r in lstDocSearch
                    group r by r.DocumentID
                        into g

                        select new
                        {
                            DocumentID = g.Key,
                            MetaValues = g.ToList()

                        }).ToList();

        List<DocSearch> list = new List<DocSearch>();

        foreach (var item in test)
        {

            foreach (var item2 in item.MetaValues)
            {
                var check = list.Exists(x => x.DocumentID == item2.DocumentID);
                if (check)
                {
                    var find = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DocumentID == item2.DocumentID);

                    find.MetaValue = find.MetaValue + ", " + item2.MetaValue;
                    find.DocPropIdentifyName = find.DocPropIdentifyName + ", " + item2.DocPropIdentifyName;
                }
                else
                {
                    DocSearch objDocSearch = new DocSearch();

                    objDocSearch.DocumentID = item2.DocumentID;
                    objDocSearch.DocPropIdentifyID = item2.DocPropIdentifyID;
                    objDocSearch.DocPropIdentifyName = item2.DocPropIdentifyName;
                    objDocSearch.MetaValue = item2.MetaValue;

                    list.Add(objDocSearch);
                }
            }
        }
```

But I would like to do this with linq rather than looping through the collection. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this ? :

```
var test = (from r in lstDocSearch
            group r by r.DocumentID
            into g
            select new
            {
                DocumentID = g.Key,
                MetaValues = String.Join(",", g.Select(o => o.MetaValue)),
                DocPropIdentifyNames = String.Join(",", g.Select(o => o.DocPropIdentifyName)),
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Spot on, I will accept the answer as soon as they allow me.